# How can I find lines that do not end in a certain character(") and then add that character using find and replace in VS Code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace

As the title says I need a Regex expression that will match a line that does not end in a certain character(") and then to substitute the entire line and append at end.
There are lines in my file that should end with " but it is missing so I need to find these lines and add the missing "
Using Regex and VS Code find & replace this expression

```
[^\n"/n](\n|$)
```

finds all lines of this sort but I cannot append as it gets rid of the last character of the string when trying to replace with

```
$1 "
```

Answer (score 3):

Put VS Code find-and-replace in regex mode. Put `.*[^"]$` in the search field, and put `$0"` in the replace field. "`$0`" in the replace field represents the whole content that was matched for each match.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the last character as you *match* it, but only use the capture group in the replacement with `$1`

You can match `[^"]$` and use the full match in the replacement like `$0 "`

Comment: ...or `(?<!"")$` and replace the zero-width match with `"`? [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zgnU9E/1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching the lines that don't end with `"`, you can search all end of the line without distinction with an optional `"`:

- search: `"?$`
- replacement: `"`

if a line already has a double quote, this one is replaced with a double quote. If a line doesn't have a double quote, a double quote is added.

Notice: don't try to do that with regex101 because a line that ends with `"` is matched twice (at the double quote position and at the end of line position), it only works in VScode.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to select anything really.

Find:  `(?<!"|^\s*)$`
Replace: `"`

The regex just checks that the end of the line `$` is not preceded by a `"` or
is not a blank line with only whitespace on it.

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VoAwSS/1)